Using Python to toggle the RGB lights in my steelseries gear
I have a bunch of steel series gear: mouse, pad, speakers, keyboard. All have RGB lights. When I go to sleep I have to manually turn off these lights.
I would like to automate this process with a python script. Doing a bunch of research on this, I figured out Steelseries provides its users with an app called steelseries.gg, which has an 'engine', which allows you to save different RGB preset configurations; at the moment I have a couple of configs: on/off.
Initially my approach was to try and see if the steelseries.gg app has an API (it has), which allows you to toggle the RGB config, also called Prism configuration (it doesn't).
I had the idea of setting a key-bind to my keyboard that determines the Prism config. I set a couple of keys: F11/F12, one sets the Prism config to "ON", the other to "OFF". Already some advancement, but this is far from a completely automated script. I then had the naive idea of using some GUI python libraries to manually trigger an F11/F12 key-press. TLDR; this triggers an abstract F11/F12 key presses at the level of windows, but fails to trigger the toggle Prism config bind I associated with my physical F11/F12 keys using the steelseries.gg app.
I imagine these ideas are some of the most obvious that a non-expert would tackle first. I am curious however if any of you experts may have a better idea on how to toggle my RGB lighting ON/OFF using a python script.
Thanks in advance!
